# Normalizing wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, normalization

If you are trying to normalize $\psi = A\sin kx$, and you find that $|A|^2 = \frac{2}{a}$, why do you take the positive square root and not the negative? What happens if you take the negative square root?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't matter what sign you choose. Notice that since $|A|^2 = \frac{2}{a}$, you could even pick $A = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}} e^{i\phi}$, so $A$ doesn't have to be real. The reason is that a wavefunction is only defined up to a global phase. The reason is that we calculate probabilites with $|\psi|^2$ and mean values of operators with $\int \psi^* \hat{O} \psi$, and none of these change if we make a substitution $\psi \to e^{i\phi} \psi$. The upshot of this is that only the absolute value of $A$ is what matters, and since we can use whatever phase we want, making it real and positive is the simplest choice. But you could use $A= - \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}$, and none of the physically observable quantities will change.